# Redmine Checklist Plugin Installation Fails

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

I had Redmine 4.0.4 working fine until I decided to try the checklist plugin.
I tried to follow the instruction on the official website: https://www.redmineup.com/pages/help/checklists/installing-redmine-checklists-plugin-on-linux

But when executing the command:

```
 bundle install --without development test --no-deployment
```

I got this:

```
Installing locked Bundler version 2.0.2...
Installing the inferred bundler version (= 2.0.2) failed.
If you'd like to update to the current bundler version (1.15.1) in this project, run `bundle update --bundler`.
The error was: bundler requires Ruby version >= 2.3.0.
```

First i don't understand why the ruby version error, 2.3.0, i have 2.5.0p0...

Second if i type bundler -v i get the ouput saying that i'm in the Bundler version 2.0.2

Third if i try to run the bundle update --bundler, this is the output:

```
You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.
```

I can't see how to solve this... What i can/must do?

And now i can't access redmine, i have this error when trying to open the site:

```
Could not find gem 'redmine_crm' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

If i can't install the plugin, at least i want to bring redmine back online.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like it requires another plugin, called redmine_crm, those are proprietary plugins, the proper place to ask for help are it's producers.

Comment: Already posted there for help...
But like i wrote, it's possible to revert this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following steps

1. Stop your server (Passenger, Puma or whatever you use)
2. Remove the plugin from plugins folder
3. Delete Gemfile.lock in Redmine's root folder
4. In command prompt, run `gem uninstall -aIx`
5. Run `gem install bundler`
6. In Redmine folder run `bundle install --without development test`
7. Try starting your server

Comment: Thanks, it didn't work the first time... Don't ask me why, but after rebooting the machine it worked.